# Laravel registration on hosting does not work

Tags: php, laravel, caching, hosting

On the local server, everything works fine. Registration takes place, and so on. But as soon as I upload to the hosting and try to register, an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3qNy.png) occurs .I deleted the file before uploading it to the `config.php` hosting service.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0pfk.png)

this error is caused when I register

Comment: Try running this command in the terminal of your hosting `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: Saud It didn't help

Comment: Can you add the error message to the question?

Comment: @sdaasdasd please also attach error log, your route list and you controller action.

Comment: @Saud I added the message in a hyperlink in the text

Comment: Could you check your browser's network tab in the developers pane, to verify the browser is actually sending a POST?